# Excluding files from only one Webpack loader in a chain

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I currently have a Webpack rule that looks like this:

```
{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack', 'babel-loader', 'angular2-template' ] }
```

I want *only* the `babel-loader` to exclude certain files, basically just passing them as is down the chain. The remainder of the loaders should not exclude those files. Thus, I can't add the files to an `exclude` for the entire rule.

Can I exclude files on a per-loader basis? If required, I'm willing to write some plugin code, though obviously out of the box would be ideal.

This is related to this Angular2 Webpack issue: (I'm trying to work around the problem) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I didn't try it myself, the documentation suggests it's possible: pass the `only` query to `babel-loader` with a value of "glob, regex, or mixed array of both".

Sources: [babel-loader options](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options) and [Babel options](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/)
Don't forget to [properly format the query](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#parsequery) value as a string, so the options parser can read it.